# Can't render partial with interpolated instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to render a partial on product pages that have the table column "group" set to "women".

In products_controller.rb I have:

```
@subnav = Spree::Product.find(params[:group])
```

Then in products#show I have:

```
<div class="subnav">
 <%= render "spree/shared/#{@subnav}_subnav" %>
</div><!--subnav -->
```

So when a product has group "women" it should render "spree/shared/women_subnav". But instead I get a "ActionView::MissingTemplate in Spree/products#show" error, saying

```
 "Missing partial spree/shared/_subnav with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl], :versions=>[:v1]}.
```

So for some reason it's not even recognizing the existence of the variable.

I've also tried

```
 @subnav = params[:group]
```

and

```
 @subnav = Product.find(params[:group]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What URL do you call to have this error ? How are defined your routes ?

Comment: http://pants.telegraphbranding.com/products/:id

Comment: Oh I see. I need :group in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because in `<%= render "spree/shared/#{@subnav}_subnav" %>`, `@subnav` is nil or blank.
It is blank because `params[:group]` is nil or blank. It is blank because params doesn't have `:group` key.

Your URL is `pants.telegraphbranding.com/products/:id`

This means that params has one key : `id`.

If you want to access to a group, you have to define a route like this :

```
pants.telegraphbranding.com/groups/:group_id/products/:id
```

Or pass the group directly in the URL: `pants.telegraphbranding.com/products/123?group_id=456`

Next, you can write

```
@subnav = Spree::Product.find(params[:group_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

as per comment you are not passing the group params to server within url.

```
 @subnav = Spree::Product.find(params[:group])
```

here @subnav will be nil and string interpolation replace "#{@subnav}" with empty string.

Also @subnav will be instance of ActiveRecord not string so you need to call the required attribute which will return string ("women" in your case).

one more note of caution check value of @subnav before rendering the partial to handle the nil value

like

```
<% unless @subnav.nil? %>
<div class="subnav">
 <%= render "spree/shared/#{@subnav.name}_subnav" %>
</div><!--subnav -->
<% end %>
```

assuming name is the attribute of ActiveRecord instance to hold the "women" value